# Merge multiple files recursively using Java

Tags: java, fileutils

I would like to merge the following .properties files into one. So for example I have structure:

```
IAS
├── default
│   ├── gateway.properties
│   └── pennytunnelservice.properties
└── FAT
    ├── gateway.properties
    ├── IAS-jer-1
    │   └── gateway.properties
    └── pennytunnelservice.properties
```

My goal is to have two merged files (in this example) pennytunnelservice.properties nad gateway.properties.

In **default/gateway.properties** is for example:

```
abc=$change.me
def=test
```

In **FAT/gateway.properties** is for example:

```
abc=123
ghi=234
```

In **FAT/pennytunnelservice.properties** is for example:

```
mno=text
```

In **FAT/IAS-jer-1/gateway.properties** is for example:

```
xyz=123
ghi=98
```

And the result should be two files with these rows:

**pennytunnelservice.properties**

```
mno=text
```

**gateway.properties**

```
abc=123
def=test
ghi=98
xyz=123
```

Do you have any idea how to do that?

---

**UPDATED !!!**

I have written something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String dirName = "/IAS";
    File file = new File(dirName);
    Map<String,Properties> files = new HashMap<>();


    Files.walkFileTree(file.toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            System.out.println(file);

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file.toString());

            prop.load(input);
            files.put(file.getFileName().toString(), prop);

            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

And the result is

```
{pennytunnelservice.properties={mno=text}, gateway.properties={abc=123, ghi=234}}
```

The problem is that files are loaded in the wrong way/order:

```
IAS/default/pennytunnelservice.properties
IAS/default/gateway.properties
IAS/FAT/IAS-jer-1/gateway.properties
IAS/FAT/pennytunnelservice.properties
IAS/FAT/gateway.properties
```

It should be:

```
IAS/default/pennytunnelservice.properties
IAS/default/gateway.properties
IAS/FAT/pennytunnelservice.properties
IAS/FAT/gateway.properties
IAS/FAT/IAS-jer-1/gateway.properties
```

Comment: I suggest following approach. Keep seperate List<Properties> one for gateway.properties and one other pennytunnelservice.properties. Parse each file and add those to correct List<Properties>. Finally, keep adding those List of Properties to a single property object. Then iterate over that final Properties object and extract key value pairs and write to a file.

Comment: Have a look here, and you might see how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004833/how-to-merge-two-java-util-properties-objects . What you will have to do is load each `Properties` with your files' content

Comment: From Javadoc "The file tree is traversed [depth-first](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-)", so you need to store `Paths` in a `Collection` and sort, then process the files.

Comment: @VenkataRaju thanks, it's a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Map<String, Properties>`.  is the .properties filename and  is the content read from the file.

Recursively, using a [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) look for property files.

For each file found, load it updating the old content in the map if the same file name has already been found.

When all files have been processed iterate over all filenames (keys in map) and for each one save a new properties file with the content gathered from all found files.

Comment: Thank you, could you check my last edit? I tried to implement one solution, but have problem - files are loaded in the wrong way/order. Could you give me a small hint?

Comment: @sipekmichal.cz: the order is givn by the graph traversal algorithm. You have to make another FileVisitor (probably derived from SimpleFileVisitor) that handles the order in the way you want (alphabetically, case insensitive, ...). In your case it seems that you want to treat the directories last.

Comment: See this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396649/order-of-traversal-in-files-walkfiletree